# Core Data not returning results on first try; works on second try - same code, no change to data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am doing a "select all" on a table of "Behavior" objects. The "select all" happens inside a *initBehaviors* method. The *initBehaviors* method is called whenever the app starts up, and when a "Done" button is tapped.

This is the "select all" code inside the *initBehaviors* method.

```
DataController *controller = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).dataController;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = controller.context;

NSFetchRequest *getBehaviors = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Behavior"];
NSArray *behResults = [context executeFetchRequest:getBehaviors error:nil];

NSLog(@"Behaviors:");
NSLog(@"%@", behResults);
```

The problem is this: we get no results when the code is triggered the first time the app starts up. However, we get (correctly) all the behaviors in Core Data on tapping the "Done" button. The done button also triggers a context save regardless if there are changes.

This is the output when the code is triggered when the app starts up:

```
2017-11-21 21:45:32.246 Sonicwarper[745:559533] CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C882488-3C85-4EA7-B036-E3B3D47F50DB/Sonicwarper.app/Sonicwarper.momd/Sonicwarper.omo'
2017-11-21 21:45:32.258 Sonicwarper[745:559533] Behaviors:
2017-11-21 21:45:32.260 Sonicwarper[745:559533] ( )
```

Note: I'm also getting a "Failed to load optimized model" problem - but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

This is the output when the code is triggered when tapping the "Done" button"

```
2017-11-21 21:53:56.788 Sonicwarper[745:559533] Behaviors: 2017-11-21 21:53:56.790 Sonicwarper[745:559533] ( "<NSManagedObject: 0x156891d0> (entity: Behavior; id: 0x156d6590 <x-coredata://679EF60E-A677-440C-84E0-771EF1A6AA0D/Behavior/p1> ; data: <fault>)", "<NSManagedObject: 0x156890a0> (entity: Behavior; id: 0x156d7830 <x-coredata://679EF60E-A677-440C-84E0-771EF1A6AA0D/Behavior/p2> ; data: <fault>)" ) 
2017-11-21 21:53:56.791 Sonicwarper[745:559533]     - Q
2017-11-21 21:53:56.791 Sonicwarper[745:559533]     - W
```

Note: "Q" and "W" are the names of 2 behaviors which are already in Core Data.

Comment: You say "whenever the app starts up" but where?  Have you completed all necessary initialisation before you make this call?

Comment: Do you have an async initialization somewhere that you are not waiting for completion to perform the first fetch? If you log `context` is it the same both times (first unsuccessful and successful fetch)?

Comment: @Russell Thanks for commenting. This code is called in a singleton object that's called for the first time in the main view controller. What initialisations are you referring to? I suppose if Core Data helper objects are no initialised - we won't even have an empty array.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for commenting. What do you mean by "log context"? You mean printing it out as NSLog(@"%@", context)? I have only 1 context, that's referenced in the singleton DataController object above.

Comment: I think @Larme and I are asking the same question! **Something** must be completing after your first call, and before you click the button.  it looks like you're making the 'initBehaviors' call too soon, and you need to wait for the CoreData controller to be initialised

Comment: @Larme I do not need to wait for any async process to complete - the data is already in Core Data.

Comment: where do you call *initBehaviors* -  'viewWIllLoad', 'viewDidLoad', 'viewDidAppear', 'appDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions', etc.,?

Comment: Hey, you guys are right. I've checked the initialization of DataController, it's async. Works fine after I've built callback after initialization is done where I can make the "select all" calls. Thanks both.

Comment: BTW: `initBehaviours` is a non-conforming method name.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad thanks for commenting. Do you have reference to documentation on the topic?

Comment: It is a convention https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-method-families